# Calling a variable outside of a function in python?

Tags: python, game-engine

I know it's been asked a hundred times before, but I never seem to be able to get a straight answer from viewing other questions.
I need a simple explanation as to how I can call a variable that was defined inside a function outside of that function anywhere else in the script.
Here is the first script:

```
#combat engine alpha stage
#individual character stats, compose of strength, speed, dexterity, STIR, experience, power, levels range 1-6
#Samoht stats strength1, speed2, dexterity3, STIR4, experience5, power6
samohtStats=(3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5)
#Crepusc stats
crepuscStats=(6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4)
import time
def askChar():
    askChar=int(input("Would you like to play as Crepusculum(1) or Samoht(2)?"))
    if askChar==1:
        print("Crepusculum: Strength-",crepuscStats[0],"Speed-",crepuscStats[1],"Dexterity-",crepuscStats[2],"STIR-",crepuscStats[3],"Experience-",crepuscStats[4],"Power-",crepuscStats[5])
        askOK=int(input("Is this your character? Yes(1) No(2)"))
        if askOK==1:
            char=1
            import arena
        elif askOK==2:
            askChar()
    elif askChar==2:
        print("Samoht: Strength-",samohtStats[0],"Speed-",samohtStats[1],"Dexterity-",samohtStats[2],"STIR-",samohtStats[3],"Experience-",samohtStats[4],"Power-",samohtStats[5])
        askOK=int(input("Is this your character? Yes(1) No(2)"))
        if askOK==1:
            char=2
            import arena
        elif askOK==2:
            askChar()
print("Welcome to TNS: Arena!(alpha)")
askChar()
```

Then there is the file "arena" I am importing:

```
#arena script
if char==1:
    print("test")
    time.sleep(3)
elif char==2:
    print("test")
    time.sleep(3)
```

As you can see, I am also importing another file and then trying to use the local variable outside of its function. I don't know if this is a problem.
I just need a simple explanation as to the right syntax as to go about fixing my problem.

Comment: Return it from your function.

Comment: ... There are just so many problems with design here it's hard to start. But sufficed to say, when you ``import`` something, you aren't just like inserting the text inline at the point of the import statement. The ``globals`` and ``locals`` scope for that imported script is completely separate from the script that it's imported into. So no, the ``char`` in the *arena* script is not the same ``char`` that's in the ``locals`` for ``askChar``

Comment: Ah. That's what I was thinking. Apologies if this seems like poor design, because it really is. I'm still learning python and a lot of the terminology is still foreign to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you import `arena` [if it gets that far], you should get a NameError complaining that there's no name `char`.

When you import a module in Python, by doing `import arena`, you're creating a name, `arena` in the scope of the import statement. If you import inside a function, then `arena` would be available in that function. If you import it in the global scope, it'll be global.

The name `arena` will reference a *module object*. Note that `module` is just another Python object type. The module object's attributes are globals in the source code for that module.

If you define `char` inside `arena.py`, then `import arena` in your main file's global namespace, you can then reference `char` as `arena.char` there.

Comment: So how would I fix this? I'm still learning Python, and this is really just an excersize, so simplicity would be appreciated.

Comment: This isn't an appropriate place to work through your code. Sorry. Try moving your code into a single file, then moving things like functions into other modules and seeing how it works.